# Apache Camel: using stream and onCompletion

Tags: java, stream, apache-camel

I have a route that needs to download one file, via HTTP.

This route is dynamically added when a message containing a command (containing the URL of HTTP resource, and URI of local file where to save it) is received, and then when the file transfer is completed I want to remove the route, thus using Camel only as a protocol translator.

I'm using Camel for this because this route falls into a project built on EIPs, where Camel is used everywhere for messaging and integration.

I used:

```
onCompletion().setBody(simple("")).bean(new Stop(getContext(), transferID));

from("stream:url?url="+from).to("stream:file?fileName="+to).routeId(this.transferID);
```

(file is big, 10-100 Gb)

I see that `onCompletion` fires before the whole file transfers, actually it transfers only a non-predictable quantity of bytes, like 100-300 kB.

Are "stream" and `onCompletion` not compatible or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: in the Bean I'm doing:

```
c.stopRoute(transferID);
c.removeRoute(transferID);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [stream component](http://camel.apache.org/stream.html) **will create a new exchange for each line** of the file.

The stream component provide an option to split on XX lines (0 by default):

> groupLines    0   Camel 2.5: To group X number of lines in the consumer.
>   For example to group 10 lines and therefore only spit out an Exchange
>   with 10 lines, instead of 1 Exchange per line.

This option is used to create new exchanges of XX lines. Here is the related code of the [StreamConsumer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-stream/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/stream/StreamConsumer.java):

```
 if (lines.size() >= endpoint.getGroupLines()) {
      // spit out lines
      Exchange exchange = endpoint.createExchange();

      // create message with the lines
      Message msg = new DefaultMessage();
      List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(lines);
      msg.setBody(endpoint.getGroupStrategy().groupLines(copy));
      exchange.setIn(msg);

      // clear lines
      lines.clear();

      getProcessor().process(exchange);
 }
```

And the **onCompletion is executed each time after an exchange completed**.

From the camel doc ([onCompletion documentation](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html)):

> triggered either always, only if completed with success, or only if
>   failed

**So your code stops the route after the first line is read**.

Apparently there is actually no way to know when the end of the file occurs with the stream component.

A nice way might have be to have a CamelSplitComplete property like in the [splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html).
That we could use like that (See [onCompletion with onWhen predicate](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) chapter):

```
onCompletion()
  .onWhen(property("CamelSplitComplete").isEqualTo("true"))
  .setBody(simple("")).bean(new Stop(getContext(), transferID));
```

**EDIT:** I was only looking for the stream consumer, but since you are also using the producer. Look at the closeOnDone property, that might do the trick.

> closeOnDone | false | Camel 2.11.0: This option is used in combination
>   with Splitter and streaming to the same file. The idea is to keep the
>   stream open and only close when the Splitter is done, to improve
>   performance. Mind this requires that you only stream to the same file,
>   and not 2 or more files.

Comment: May I suggest to add a note on the documentation about this behaviour?

Comment: It's not clear that the stream will work this way, and the header condition it's not working. Inspecting the exchanges coming to the onCompletion route I don't find any useful header.

Comment: I update my answer to provide more info on stream component. I was not sure about the header. Have you try to look in the properties ? It might be something like this: `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.SPLIT_COMPLETE)`

Comment: I did `onCompletion().to("activemq:queue:INSPECT");` and this is the last Message that goes through: http://goo.gl/KoJlb5
Then I tried to simply print Exchange.getProperies() and Exchange.getIn().getHeaders(), got this: http://pastebin.com/395UZzZL

Comment: I inspected the github source you linked. It looks like the splitting is done without using a splitter, but in `void processLine(String line)` in `StreamConsumer.java`. Looking at that I assume no property or header gets set on last exchange leaving the stream, and also that the stream, if grouping, can't transfer files that have a number of lines not an exact multiple of groupLines, think of 10 lines text file, with groupLines=7, the first 7 lines leave the stream in the first Exchange, last 3 lines get added to `List<String> lines` but not hitting the threshold they aren't sent out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For now there is no way to know when this is the end of the file. This is an issue of the component. I think we could ask to add this functionality.

Comment: I think you're more qualified to open the issue in Camel's JIRA, or where it belongs to be. Meanwhile I'll be doing a quick n' dirty patch on stream component locally, to bring on. Thank you.

Comment: Otherwise, you could try with the http component: http://camel.apache.org/http.html

Comment: I need to transfer big files, HTTP component causes Heap Memory Errors.
I'm trying with this patch, which works fine if you're using text files (sends at most one extra exchange with null body): http://pastebin.com/JTFPpgHE
Also, documentation says stream endpoints support either String or byte[] but the component is actually producing List<String>, this makes transferring binary files (or streams) impossible. This requires a major refactor of the component, it should read binary files in "fixed size" chunks and send them as a byte[] as required from documentation.